# Request Permission after selected option(either camera or gallery) from intent chooser in android

Tags: android, runtime-permissions, android-intent-chooser

I have created an intent chooser containing Gallery, Photos and Camera apps. Now for the devices running on Android 6.0 or greater I want to ask the run time permissions after app is selected from chooser like if user selects gallery option I will ask storage permission only and in case if user select camera option I will ask camera and storage both permissions if not given before.

Can someone help me to do so?

Here is my code

```
public void openImageIntent() {
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fname = "ABCD_" + timeStamp;
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(storageDir, fname);
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    //Gallery.
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    //Create the Chooser
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));


    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 65530);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking for permissions at run-time, Android M+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608731/asking-for-permissions-at-run-time-android-m)

Comment: Try and check this one: https://theartofdev.com/2015/02/15/android-cropping-image-from-camera-or-gallery/

Comment: Thanks @Nitin. This Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203230/how-to-tell-which-app-was-selected-by-intent-createchooser/32203659#32203659 shared by you helped me.

Comment: Great.. And you solved that?

Comment: Upload the answer and you can mark it as answer after some minutes. That  will also helpful to other, thanks.

Comment: For sure Nitin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all for your support.

I solved it myself.

I appended below code in above method

```
Intent receiver = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntentOptionReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //Create the Chooser
        final Intent chooserIntent;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
        } else {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
        }
```

Here is my broadcast receiver(IntentOptionReceiver) to notify which intent chooser option selected

```
public class IntentOptionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
            Log.e("intentOptionReceiver", "Intent option clicked info" + intent.getExtras().get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to enter your broadcast receiver inside manifest.

Answer (score 1):

check permission using this code when ever.

what permission need give in to the array.

```
if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    }
```

add this method also

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length <= 0 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but how would I get know which app is selected from intent chooser(camera or gallery). I am not able to get the selected intent from intent chooser.

Comment: @SapnaSharma You have to request both permission, because you cannot assume which one user will select.

Comment: You are right @Nitin but whatsapp handles it when changing profile pic. I do not know how.

Comment: @SapnaSharma I found this that will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203659/7806873

Comment: above has tell how get permission runtime. u customize for u click camera then check camera permission and u choose gallery then check external permission that's ur function

Comment: @Bhuvaneshwaran here is the issue of getting click callback(either clicked gallery or camera)

Comment: @SapnaSharma "here is the issue of getting click callback" what issue getting callback

Answer (score 0):

> This method returns true if the app has Read External Storage Permission

```
 private boolean hasReadExternalStoragePermission() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                int permissionCheck = checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

> Wrap the actions that require permission with hasReadExternalStoragePermission method.

```
 public void openGallery() {

        if (hasReadExternalStoragePermission()) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    }
```

Please expand more on your own, use Manifest.permission_group instead of Manifest.permission, In places where you need to request multiple permission at once.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: this question is not only about asking runtime permissions. May be I did not explained it well. I want to ask storage or camera permissions just after user select app from intent chooser depending on which app user selects.

Comment: Call intent to open camera only if you have storage permission that way the camera chooser intent won't open. If you don't have storage permission